# Unable to pass URL with & in ARM template on Azure

Tags: bash, azure, blob, azure-rm-template

```
 "variables": {

        "scriptBaseURL": "https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/",
        "sasTokenURL": "?st=2018-04-11T14%3A00%3A00Z&se=2020-04-13T14%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=9bzbHSDFEPds1mrTxCdCgaF7wnRh%2FsX8sQeNnVMucE%3D",
        "filePath": "[concat(variables('scriptBaseURL'), 'test.rpm', variables('sasTokenURL'))]",
        "mongoDBScript": "[concat(variables('scriptBaseURL'), 'install-mongodb-3.4.sh', variables('sasTokenURL'))]",
        "oracleJDKScript": "[concat(variables('scriptBaseURL'), 'install-oracle-jdk-8.sh', variables('sasTokenURL'))]",
        "install-dependencies": "[concat(variables('mongoDBScript'), ',', variables('oracleJDKScript'))]",
        "port1": 8080,
        "port2": 8090

}

{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/install-script')]",
    "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
           "fileUris": "[split(variables('install-dependencies'), ',')]",
           "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh install-dependencies.sh', ' ', variables('port1'), ' ', variables('port2'), ' ', variables('filePath'))]"
        }          
    }
}
```

I am passing variables('filePath') in this line -> "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh install-dependencies.sh', ' ', variables('port1'), ' ', variables('port2'), ' ', variables('filePath'))]"

When I am passing filePath to install-dependencies.sh script, I get the following value as 3rd parameter

```
https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/2018-04-03/builds/test.rpm?st=2018-04-11T14%3A00%3A00Z
```

instead of

```
https://sample.blob.core.windows.net/test/2018-04-03/builds/test.rpm?st=2018-04-11T14%3A00%3A00Z&se=2020-04-13T14%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=9bzbHSDFEPds1mrTxCdCgaF7wnRh%2FsX8sQeNnVMucE%3D
```

How to solve this?

Comment: How are you passing the URL to the script?  Update that. You should let know which part of this involves `bash` shell

Comment: I am passing    variables('filePath') in this line ->         "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh install-dependencies.sh', ' ', variables('port1'), ' ', variables('port2'), ' ', variables('filePath'))]"

Comment: Please update that to the question and _not_ in comments

Comment: @Inian I have updated

Comment: try to print this value as output and see what you are getting a I just tried that with your values and it is working fine.

Comment: I did printed. URL values cut after &

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this by using the below command

```
       "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh install-dependencies.sh', ' ', variables('port1'), ' ', variables('port2'), ' ', '\"', variables('filePath'), '\"')]"
```